# Error cloning git repo onto exFAT usb drive

Tags: usb-drive, git, exfat

Running Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty), I have mounted an exFAT formatted USB drive. While attempting to `git clone` a repo onto it, I've run into the following error:

```
Cloning into 'rschedule'...
error: chmod on /media/john/John/apps/rschedule/.git/config.lock 
failed: Function not implemented
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

Cloning the repo onto my computer's local file system works normally. I can also otherwise access the USB drive normally (i.e. read / create files).

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong?

*Additional information which is hopefully irrelevant: Ubuntu is running on a Chromebook using [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).*

#### Edit:

A possibly related question: [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition). Unfortunately, assuming it is related, I haven't been able to figure out how to translate that question / answers to my problem.

Comment: Please run `sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/fvat/usb` and try again!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thanks! Unfortunately, that command results in the following error: `chmod: changing permissions of '/media/john/John': Function not implemented`

Comment: ok have a look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes use the `git config core.fileMode false` version so it's not globally set

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen the git directory is currently remotely hosted on gitlab. Attempting to run `git config` outside of a git repository is giving me a `fatal: not in a git repository` error

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen maybe I'm running into the same problem described in the ["How to use 'chmod'..."](https://askubuntu.com/a/11843/534308) question I linked to? Namely "The mode is determined by the partition's mount options (you cannot change it via chmod)." If so, I'm not sure what mount options I need in order to make things work.

Comment: The options would be `sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever`. Ofcourse you will umount it first then remount it `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` I presume it's `/dev/sdb1`!!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen so I think I made some progress with `sudo mount -t exfat -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever` (note: I needed to change `vfat` format to `exfat`). This mounts the USB but the mounted folder is owned by the root user (rather than the current user) which messes things up and (I think) forces all commands to be run with `sudo`. Any idea how I can accomplish this so the mounted folder is owned by the current user? Simply running the `mount` command without `sudo` produces a `mount: only root can do that` error. Thanks!!

Comment: Add the `umask=000` option to mount command!

Comment: exfat filesystem does not have Unix style file persmission so you cannot chmod on it.

Comment: maybe you can run `git config --global core.fileMode false` and try again.

Comment: @AlvinLiang thanks for the help. Unfortunately using `git config --global core.fileMode false` still results in the same error when attempting to `git clone`.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen adding the `umask=000` to the mount command still results in the root user having ownership permissions of the file. I should also say, for completeness sake, that I've tried to run `git clone` after each one of these changes and I'm still running into the same error--I'm guessing it's because the USB is mounted with the incorrect permissions. If I inspect the USB's permissions after mounting it normally (i.e. just plugging it in and mounting via the GUI), then it says `owner: me` & `group: john`. When mounting using your suggestion, it says `owner: root` & `group: root`.

Comment: @AlvinLiang it sounds like maybe I simply cannot `git clone` onto an `exfat` formatted USB drive?

Comment: After some digging, git actually tries to set fileMode to false when it's not applicable.  Your problem is actually git can't do some operation on the repository's git config.  I don't think one can easily fix this problem without change git code.

Comment: a similar problem on other system https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2441

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I think I'm able to get the proper permissions when mounting using `sudo mount -t exfat -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda2 /media/john` (where `1000` is the user id and group id). Unfortunately, this still doesn't fix the `git clone` problem (I also tried adding `umask=000`, no luck). It looks like I was wrong and the  [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/11843#11843) question is unrelated to this one. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @AlvinLiang thanks for finding that! It does sound like the termux issue you linked to may be related. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assembling from the comments above:

Mounting with

```
sudo mount -t exfat -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda1 mnt
```

where `mnt` is in my home directory thus owned by me
and then doing

```
git -c core.fileMode=false clone ../whatever-bare-repo.git/
```

seems to work correctly